# Renormalization in effective field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I have tried to solve these two questions. I have read different papers and textbooks in order to get an answer but all effort proved abortive. Someone should kindly assist in these equations.[image]

Comment: Although posed as a homework and exercises question, which might be off topic tor that reason, I do not think it should be considered as such. For one thing, it is an advanced topic, not tedious high school homework. For another, it invites a conceptual answer which I think is on-topic. Unfortunately I do not myself feel equipped to give such an answer, but I would like to see one.

Comment: Could you please provide details about appeared quantities? What is $C$?

Comment: C is a constant tensor force

Comment: @CharlesFrancis The tediousness (or lack thereof) of a homework question does not render it more or less of a homework question.  I agree with you that the topic is interesting and that good conceptual questions and answers about renormalization would be at home here, but OP has literally posted a jpg of their homework assignment with no indication of the underlying concepts with which they are struggling.  Barring a complete overhaul of this question (which would be welcome), it should be closed as off-topic.